# Why "EA.Project.GeneratePackage" method does not generate the code?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I'm working on an add-in for EA that can generate C code from a package. You can see a piece of my code below. I can see that GUID and the GUID in XML format are correct. But for some reason, the GeneratePackage method does not generate any code at all. Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix the issue?

```
public void generateCode(EA.Repository repository)
{
    // step one: get the GUID of the package you want to generate code from
    string thePackageGUID = repository.ProjectGUID;
    MessageBox.Show(thePackageGUID);

    // step two: use the package GUID to access the package - seems like it's not relevant
    //EA.Package thePackage = repository.GetPackageByGuid (thePackageGUID);
    // step three: access the project through the interface "GetProjectInterface"
    EA.Project theProject = repository.GetProjectInterface();

    // step four: convert GUID to XML format
    string GUIDinXML = theProject.GUIDtoXML(thePackageGUID);
    MessageBox.Show(GUIDinXML);
    MessageBox.Show("That was the GUID in XML format. Did u see it?");

    // step five: access the code generation utility function
    string ExtraOptions = "1";
    Boolean generationFlag = theProject.GeneratePackage(GUIDinXML, ExtraOptions);
    if (generationFlag == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GUIDinXML);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, C code was not generated.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is step one

```
// step one: get the GUID of the package you want to generate code from
string thePackageGUID = repository.ProjectGUID;
```

The `ProjectGUID` you are using is the unique identifier of your whole project (AKA model, AKA Repository), and does not identify a package.

You'll need to somehow get hold of a package.

There are a few ways you could do that

- Allow your user to select a package using `Repository.InvokeConstructPicker`
- Use the selected package in the project browser using `Repository.GetTreeSelectedPackage`
- Use `Repository.SQLQuery` to figure out which package(s) need generating
- Use a hardcoded reference to a package GUID(s)
- Use a configuration file to store the package GUID(s)

Comment: So you need to get one of the views below the root...

Comment: @qwerty_so or allow the user to select a package, or determine the package in another way (hardcoded, configuration, query,...)

Comment: It was just missing in the answer :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I used InvokeConstructPicker method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified version of the code.
It allows you select the package, and successfully generates the code.

```
    // this function retrives the GUID of the selected item, accesses the item and initializes the EA auto code generation
    public void generateCode(EA.Repository repository)
    {
        // get the ID of the selected item (I only included Package)
        // InvokeConstructPicker can include all element types. Modify it to include more types, if needed
        int elementID = repository.InvokeConstructPicker("IncludedTypes=Package");

        // convert TypeID to string - it is needed only for displaying
        string str_elementID = Convert.ToString(elementID);
        MessageBox.Show("The element ID is:   " + str_elementID);

        // get the element knowing its ID
        EA.Element element = repository.GetElementByID(elementID);

        // now the element is known. retrive and display the element GUID
        MessageBox.Show("The element GUID is:   " + element.ElementGUID);

        // get the relevant package, knowing one of its elements and element's GUID
        // this line can be removed, if "Package" is the only type included in InvokeConstructPicker
        EA.Package package = repository.GetPackageByGuid(element.ElementGUID);

        // display the package GUID
        MessageBox.Show("The package GUID is:   " + package.PackageGUID);

        // access the project (and therefore the package) using the interface "GetProjectInterface"
        EA.Project theProject = repository.GetProjectInterface();

        // convert the package GUID to XML format
        // if "Package" is the only included type, in the line below the parameter can be switched to "element.ElementGUID"
        string GUIDinXML = theProject.GUIDtoXML(package.PackageGUID);
        MessageBox.Show("The package GUID in XML format is:   " + GUIDinXML);

        // access the code generation utility function
        bool generationFlag = theProject.GeneratePackage(GUIDinXML, "1");
        if (generationFlag == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Code is generated.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, C code was not generated.");
        }
    }
```